# Therapy Schedule Generator

Tags: open-source, scheduling, health

I am looking for software (preferably free), that can create schedule for rehab center. There are few types of Therapists, therapy rooms (some of them are common and some of them are for specific therapies), patients with diagnosis and prescription of therapies (for example physiotherapy 10 hours a month during 2 month).

Here is what I want to do: Create rooms with types; Create therapists and assign them to rooms or to a group of rooms, choose when the therapists are available, arrange their working hours; Create therapies and assign them to therapists; Create patients with diagnosis and prescriptions; Choose options for generating schedule as - maximum therapies per day/week for therapist/patient and etc.

Here is what I want to get: Generated schedule for therapists and patients with least free time between therapies.

The software has to arrange at least 10 rooms, 15-20 therapists, >50 patients a month, >500 hours of therapies a week.